# vertically center text beside input field in IE 7/ IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, centering

**Problem:**

I want to vertically center the text on the left side of the input field. Also I want to center the calendar icon.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dateselect">
    <div id="arrivalContainer">
        <span class="annotation">Anreise</span>
        <input type="text" name="arrival" id="arrival" class="input-styling" maxlength="10" size="10" />
    </div>
    <div id="departureContainer">
        <span class="annotation">Abreise</span>
        <input type="text" name="departure" id="departure" class="input-styling" maxlength="10" size="10" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#dateselect {
    padding-top: 14px;
}

#arrivalContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}

#departureContainer {
    float: right;
    width: 160px;
}

#arrival {
    height: 25px;
    width: 68px;
}

#departure {
    height: 25px;
    width: 68px;
}

.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    left: 3px;
}

.input-styling {
    color: #575756;
    font-family: "Myriad Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

**Live example:**
http://bfb.bplaced.net/

The `span` element should be `display: inline-block;` I think. I tried it with the `line-height` and the `display: table-cell;` approach. I get it work in all browsers except IE7 and IE8.

I know it is an often occuring problem but perhaps you could give me some advice.

### Solution:

**HTML:**

I tried it with `valign="middle"` but IE8 had still problems. I ended up with this:

```
<div id="arrivalContainer">
    <div class="calendarText"><span class="annotation">Anreise</span></div>
    <div class="calendarInput"><input type="text" name="arrival" id="arrival" class="input-styling" maxlength="10" size="10" /></div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.calendarText {
    float:left;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-right:5px;
}

.calendarInput {
    float: left;
}
```

For all IE version I have conditional stylesheets.

Comment: use same line-height as the height of the input field or what ever you put your text inside - if that dont work use padding

Answer (score 1):

Try `vertical-align:middle;` for both your image and your text divs.

Answer (score 0):

This should vertically center the text, by forcing it to display at 25px tall (same as your input field). Line-height then vertically centers the line at 25px tall, too.

```
.annotation {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    height: 27px; /* +2px for border */
    line-height: 27px;
}
```

Comment: Did you see the link to the live example? I tried your code (link: http://bfb.bplaced.net/ie-test/) but the calendar icon only looks OK in IE7 mode. The `.annotation` is not vertically centered.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I updated the link http://bfb.bplaced.net/ie-test/ with your code. Until now I only tried it with putting an IE9 into IE7/IE8 mode. Here the text is not centered ...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
annotation {
 position:realtive;
 top: -5px; /*adjust to value that visually centers your text*/
}
```

for you calendar do the same.